# How to divide div into percentages but keep one constant width value div on left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 boxes, I want box1 to have 50px width on the left, and the 3 remaining boxes must fill in the rest of screen, they should be resizable. How can I achieve this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/DBnSp/**

```css
.box1
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

.box2
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}

.box3
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

.box4
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you use jquery/javascript or do you need a pure css solution?

Comment: fill in the space means the entire width of the browser must be occupied by the three blocks?

Comment: sit back and enjoy :P

Comment: @AliCarik If your solution is not listed as answer already, post it as answer to your question, even if you would prefer another answer over your own solution, probably it will be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to do this:

<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/WT2Wh/)</kbd>

```
width: calc((100% - 50px) / 3);
```

This works well for this scenario, but if you had a lot of fixed values, it could get a little complex. Basically, it calculates the space you want to fill (100% of the screen, minus the 50px for the first box), and divides it into 3 chunks.

Understand that calc() is part of CSS3, and is not universally supported. Here is a good site for seeing what browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: but in your fiddle..all blocks are invisible except the first one...why??

Comment: @AliCarik, see that JsFiddle kind of button type of thing on the second line?

Comment: @RitabrataGautam I am not sure why you cannot see it, but if I had to guess, your browser does not support calc. See this link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: chrome..but i dont know the version

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the percentage width DIVs inside an outer DIV that has a fixed left margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/DBnSp/1/

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box-right">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div>
</div>

.box1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.box-right {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.box2, .box3, .box4 {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.box2 { background: yellow; }
.box3 { background: blue; }
.box4 { background: green; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the use of `display` tables, you can set the first div to a fixed width and let the rest of the div's take the remaining space evenly!
First create a wrapper width `display:table` and `width:100%;` (or any other width)

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Now set the boxes to `display:table-cell`

```
.stretch
{
   display: table-cell;
}
```

And fix the first one width a fixed width

```
.box1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DBnSp/4/

No floats, no percentages, and very well supported!